# webpack 4 : bundle js not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I recently upgraded to webpack 4. The page is getting loaded successfully and whenever changes happened it refreshes the page automatically using webpack-dev-server. It does very nice but in the console it shows below error

> GET http://localhost:8090/build/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

And some times when ever there is id in the URL it appends the id to bundle js url like below

> http://localhost:8090/16/build/bundle.js

I tried many ways with Stack Overflow answers and GitHub solutions but none of them working for me. Below are module details

> "webpack": "^4.15.0",
>       "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
>       "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
>       "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
>       "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
>       "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
>       "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
>       "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
>       "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
>       "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: [
        "whatwg-fetch",
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'babel-polyfill',
        "./src/index.js"
        ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
        //make sure port 8090 is used when launching webpack-dev-server
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "index.html"
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.js$|\.jsx$|\.css$|\.html$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // enable HMR globally

    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf)$/,
                loader: "file-loader"  
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve("./src"),
            path.resolve("./node_modules")
        ],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        watchOptions: {
        // Needed for Windows Subsystem for Linux dev environment:
            poll: true
        },
        contentBase: "/build"
    },
    devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
    node: {
        child_process : "empty",
        fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

My index.html is placed in root directory

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="App">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you check if the bundle.js file is actually in the dist folder?

Comment: I don't have dist folder. I have build folder and the bundle file generated under it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found answer after going through all the github answers related to this issue. I finally end up in figuring out the issue in in my index.html

The problem mostly with pointing bundle js in index.html. The reason webpack bundle.js not found because I specified wrong path in my index.html.

The below one resolved my issue.

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wonderful! I had set these references to "./bundle.js" instead, which had the effect that paths with one URL segment, e.g. "/sources" was resolved properly when doing a page reload, while "/sources/new" etc. failed.

Comment: In my case, I simply forgot to provide `webpack.output.publicPath`.